# Can't understand what the flaw in my logic is:

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to choose how many numbers they want to input, then it compares all the values that the user inputs, to find which ones the largest. For some reason it only seems to compare the last two values that are entered, I can't figure out where my logic is going wrong.

```
def number_of_inputs():
        n = input("how many n values would you like ");
        values = [];
        a = 0;
        n = int(n);
        for a in range (n):
            c= int(input("Enter a value "));
            values.append(c);
            a=a+1;
        b = sum(values)
        largest_num(values,n,b);
def largest_num(values,n,b):
    a = 0;
    start = 0;
    for start in range(n):

        for a in range (n):
                if((values[start])-(values[a])>0):
                    largest = values[start]
                    a = a+1;

        print(largest);
number_of_inputs();
```

Comment: Could you give a better title please? They are meant to give users and idea of the post and draw in potential answerers...

Comment: If you want us to help you understand what's wrong with your logic you should at least try to explain it, we don't live in your head... You could also step through your code manually to figure out why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Have you ever tried debugging your code? Simplest way is to add some print statements, display the working state of your code. Believe it or not, it learning the skill of debugging will mean you don't get downvoted so much next time you have to ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just need the largest number, removing the unwanted code. You do not need the nested loop here. Update your function to:

```
def largest_num(values,n,b):
    a = 0;
    start = 0;
    for i in range(n - 1):
            if(values[i+1] > values[i]:
                largest = values[i+1]
            else: 
                largest = values[i]
    print(largest)
```

You may achieve the same using built-in `max()` as:

```
>>> max([1, 5, 2, 10, 4])
10
```

Comment: @JulienBernu: Was on the way of making the edit. Still thanks for pointing, in case I would have missed ;)